# Can I use the AND operator multiple times with the WHERE clause in a correlated subquery?

Tags: sql

I have a table with a functional dependency of EmpID determins (EmpLastName, EmpFirstName, Phone). Can I use AND multiple times in a WHERE clause to include all the attributes?

```
SELECT T1.EmpID, A1.EmpLastName, A1.EmpFirstName, A1.Phone
        FROM EMPLOYEE AS A1
    WHERE EXISTS 
          (SELECT A2.EmpID
          FROM EMPLOYEE AS A2
          WHERE A1.EmpID = A2.EmpID
          AND A1.EmpLastName <> A2.EmpLastName
          AND A1.EmpFirstName <> A2.EmpFirstName
          AND A1.Phone <> A2.Phone);
```

I am hoping that the code will display the values of any row that violate the functional dependency.

Comment: This should do what you want . . . although it will not find rows where the difference is in the `NULL` values

Answer (score 0):

Affirmative. Yes, of course you can.